# When configuring mTLS between two spring boot applications, how should the configuration of the client go?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, keystore, mtls

For mTLS,  I understand that both client and server should have truststore and keystore configured. For the server side application, I have used the spring configuration
*server.ssl.trust-xxx, server.ssl.key-xxx* properties to successfully configure it.

And for the client side,  I read that the truststore should be defined with
*-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path/to/truststore>*.  **Now client side keystore configuration puzzles me**.  Neither *-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore* nor *server.ssl.key-xxx* works for me. I have enabled the *javax.net.debug=all* and see that the truststore is loaded but keystore not when client side application starts.  I would expect something like this in the log, but no.

```
SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:164|found key for : myalias
```

Maybe there is some configuration I have turned on? Thank you so much for the help.